# How to change UIButton text when its value is updated in a pop-up view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

Here, I have a VC with a Table View that contains cells with a "Set time" button. When I tap the "Set time" button, it segues to a pop-up screen. This is where I can tap "Save Time" button to save the time (ex: "1:30") and dismiss the pop-up.

After the pop-up is dismissed, I want to update the text of "Set time" button in the Table View row that was selected to show the saved time (ex: "1:30"). When I run my code, my button text is not updated in the Table View after the time is saved in the pop-up screen.

[image: VC with Table View] **-segue->** [image: Pop-up screen]

**VC with Table View**

```
class TaskListViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var savedTaskTime = [String]()
    var selectedTaskTime = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        taskList.delegate = self
        taskList.dataSource = self
    }

    // Unwind segue 
    @IBAction func selectTimeDidSaveTime(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        let controller = segue.source as! SelectTimeViewController
        selectedTaskTime = controller.selectedTaskTime
    }
}

extension TaskListViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell
        
        // Configure timeButton title
        cell.timeButton.tag = indexPath.row
        
        if selectedTaskTime != "" {
            cell.timeButton.setTitle(savedTaskTime[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
        }
        return cell
    } 
}
```

**Pop-up VC**

```
class SelectTimeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var hour: String = "0"
    var min: String = "00"
    var selectedTaskTime = ""
    
    @IBOutlet weak var setTimeLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBAction func saveTimeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if setTimeLabel.text != "0:00" {
            selectedTaskTime = "\(hour + ":" + min)"
        } else {
            // *Code for error alert*
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
  
        updateTimeLabel()
        // *Code to initialize slider*
    }
    
    // Update Time Label with Slider Value
    func updateTimeLabel() {
        // *Code to convert slider value to timeSet value*

        setTimeLabel.text = timeSet
    }
    
    // Segue runs when unwind segue is triggered
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "setTime" {
            let controller = segue.destination as! TaskListViewController
            controller.selectedTaskTime = selectedTaskTime
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if buttons are in tableView, you should update the selected tableView row by;

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: /* .none or whatever */)
```

in your case, you should manage to update "controller.taskList.reloadRows" or keep selected row and update it in

```
selectedTaskTime: String { 
  didSet {
 
         }
       }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I put in "controller.taskList.reloadRows(at:with:)" into my pop-up VC's prepare(for:sender:) method. How would you suggest that I pass the selected row to the "at: [IndexPath]" parameter?